# Restarting Mysql 5.7 Server Issue On Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Mysql server is running on ubuntu, no problem with that.

1. But i can't restart the server.

   sudo service mysql restart => mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
2. Status command says it's not running even though it is running.

   sudo service mysql status => * MYSQL Community Server 5.7.12 is not running.

For now i have to reboot the computer to restart the mysql server.

Comment: `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown` sometimes adding the -P port ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/116100 . Something is latched onto that port. So running it in safe mode won't bind to it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.